# How to exclude float values from a switch statement?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

On a study guide for a test, my teacher told us we need to know how to make a switch statement but it must exclude float values. In our study group we played around with the idea of using "auto" but we aren't really sure how to achieve was he is asking. Any suggestions?

Comment: The cases of a switch must be integers, so it's not clear what this qusetion is about

Comment: And auto won't fix this.

Comment: @M.M Yeah, it can only be integers or char values but he said something about switch statements will accept float values but it will cause an infinite loop or something. It is unclear, I personally don't see a way to specifically exclude these values

Comment: Try it yourself, float aFloatNum = 3.f;  switch (aFloatNum) { case1: }   Error: switch expression must have integral or enum type, switch expression of type float is illegal
 
 
}

Comment: A `switch` isn't a loop, so it cannot cause an infinite loop. You need to ask your teacher for clarification, we cannot answer this question for you

Comment: Because C++ is statically typed the compiler knows what type the switch is based on before the program runs. It's not like during runtime you "might" get a double or you "might" get an std::vector. Maybe they meant for examples where there is a float you have to round to the closest integer and use an integer based switch.

Comment: C++ supports for a switch statement only char, int and enum, not string or float type.

Comment: @nick_g, or `short` or `long` or `long long` or unsigned versions of those, or `wchar_t` or `signed char` or `bool` plus any implementation defined integral types.  (The phrase you are looking for is *integral types* which covers char as well.)  There are also the class types with an implicit conversion to integral or enum types.

Comment: @Martin Bonner +1, those types too :)

Answer (score 4):

The expression used in the condition of a [`switch` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) must be:

> any expression of integral or enumeration type, or of a class type contextually implicitly convertible to an integral or enumeration type, or a declaration of a single non-array variable of such type with a brace-or-equals initializer.

A floating point type does not match any of those.

You said:

> but it must exclude float values.

There is nothing that you need to do to exclude use of floating point expressions in the condition of a `switch` statement.

Your compiler should report an error if you try to use:

```
double x;
std::cin >> x;
switch (x)
{
  ... 
}
```